# How to limit number of displayed items in html.dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I have a `html.dropdownlist` on my webpage as follows:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("MyDropDown", Model.Data, new { @class = "dropdown"})%>
```

I am populating the dropdown with ~80 items.

The issue is that when I click the dropdown the list of items is rendered from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen.

How can I set up the dropdownlist so that it only displays a maximum of 20 items when the dropdown menu is clicked (i.e. user needs to scroll down to see items 21 - 80)?

I was anticipating (!) that there would be a `html.dropdownlist` property to control the number of displayed items that would allow something like the following e.g.:

```
<% =Html.DropDownList("MyDropDown", Model.Data, new { @class = "dropdown", rows ="20"}) %>
```

From research I have been doing on the msdn website it appears that there is no such property and that each browser has its own rules of how many items are displayed in a dropdownlist (?).

I am using IE6 and IE7.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no such property. The number of rows shown before displaying a vertical scrollbar will vary depending on the browser. If you want to control this behavior you might need to implement your own `select` control using divs, etc...

Answer (score 1):

[FlexBox](http://flexbox.codeplex.com/) allows you to "page" the rows.